# MSBI: how to create a measure with DAX that implements statistical de-identification?

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular, msbi

I need to apply statistical de-identification rules in an MSBI Tabular model. An example of the kinds of rules I'm trying to implement are: if N < 20,000, then any row less than 11 must be combined with other rows.
Example: I reports counts of Foo by Dimension Bar. Since the total (in this ALLSELECTED context) is less than 20K Foo, this output is not valid:

Bar 1: 500

Bar 2: 400

Bar 3: 100

Bar 4: 11

Total: 1011

The valid output would be valid:

Bar 1: 500

Bar 2: 400

**Bar 3 & 4: 111**

Total: 1011

I want to use a measure so that when users change from Dimension Bar to Dimension Baz, or when I change the slicers being used, I want these rules to recalculate on the fly - so just combining the rows for that one dimension in the model is not the solution I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have discovered that DAX is the wrong place to implement this - we are doing this in MDX.  Please see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527568/ssas-mdx-calculate-running-total-but-exclude-less-significant-rows) for the question and solution regarding how we did that.