# SSAS MDX Calculate running total but exclude less significant rows

Tags: ssas, mdx, cumulative-sum

Old SQL developer, new to MDX:  Need help with a requirement to include small totals in a running total but not show the contributing rows of those small totals.

Consider this data

```
                Amount    Running Total
     Denver     6,321     6,321
     Portland   8,426    14,747
     Boise     19,222    33,969
     Helena    23,257    57,226
     Bozeman   31,225    88,451
     Seattle   36,894   125,345
```

My requirement is to not show any amounts under 15,000 but instead show the running total that includes them.  I must not show amounts or running totals less than 15,000.  This is to insure that small numbers can't be identified to specific cities.

like this:

```
                Amount    Running Total
     Other     19,222    33,969
     Helena    23,257    57,226
     Bozeman   31,225    88,451
     Seattle   36,894   125,345
```

Or, ideally, what is needed:

```
                Amount
     Other     33,969
     Helena    23,257
     Bozeman   31,225
     Seattle   36,894
```

Thanks for any assistance
MartinA

Comment: Can you show some code you have tried?

Comment: Ok, here's some code that provides the running total and a filter to exclude amounts less than 15,000.  Undoubtedly inelegant.

Comment: WITH 
SET [OrderedSet] AS
Nonempty
 (
 ORDER
  ([Geo].[City].[City].Members,
   [Measures].[Amount],
   BASC
  )
 )
MEMBER [Measures].[RowNumber] AS
 Rank([Geo].[City].CURRENTMEMBER,
   [OrderedSet]
  )
MEMBER [Measures].[Running Total] as 
 Sum(
  Head
   ([OrderedSet], 
    (
    [Measures].[RowNumber],
    [Geo].[City].CurrentMember)
   ),
   [Measures].[Amount]
  )
SELECT
 {
  [Measures].[Amount],
  [Measures].[Running Total]
 } ON 0,
 FILTER(
   {[OrderedSet]} 
   , [Measures].[Running Total] > 15000 )
ON 1
FROM [TheCube]

Comment: So you already have a working solution?

Comment: It is partially solved.  The remaining piece is that the row label for the consolidated rows needs to be overridden to be 'Other'.  In my example, Denver, Portland, and Boise get consolidated but the label is 'Boise'.  To get this solution to work for me, I need a way to override the label to 'Other'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few whiteboard sessions, my co-conspirator came up with a simple solution:  Add a new measure, calculating the difference between the running total and the city amount.  When this difference is less than the threshold, then this will be the rolled up row that is to contain the City name of “Other” and also use the running total rather than city total.  Kudos to [Tyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3097559/tysonwright)

Here's some example code:

```
WITH 
SET [OrderedSet] AS
Nonempty
    (
    ORDER
        ([Age].[Age Group B].[Age Group B].Members,
         [Measures].[Emergency Room Visits per 1,000 Member Months],
         BASC
        )
    )
MEMBER [Measures].[RowNumber] AS
    Rank([Age].[Age Group B].CURRENTMEMBER,
         [OrderedSet]
        )
MEMBER [Measures].[Running Total] as 
    Sum(
        Head
            ([OrderedSet], 
             ([Measures].[RowNumber],[Age].[Age Group B].CurrentMember)
            ),
            [Measures].[Emergency Room Visits per 1,000 Member Months]
        )
MEMBER [Measures].[Ttl_RunTtl_Diff] AS
    [Measures].[Running Total] - [Measures].[Emergency Room Visits per 1,000 Member Months]
MEMBER MEASURES.NewAge AS 
    IIF([Measures].[Ttl_RunTtl_Diff] = 0 OR [Measures].[Ttl_RunTtl_Diff]>15000 
        , [Age].[Age Group B].CURRENTMEMBER.Name, "Other") 
MEMBER MEASURES.NewTotal AS 
    IIF([Measures].[Ttl_RunTtl_Diff] = 0 OR [Measures].[Ttl_RunTtl_Diff]>15000 
        , [Measures].[Emergency Room Visits per 1,000 Member Months], [Measures].[Running Total]) 
SELECT NON EMPTY 
  { 
  [Measures].[Emergency Room Visits per 1,000 Member Months],
  [Measures].[Member Months],
  [Measures].[Emergency Room Visits],
  [Measures].[Running Total],
  [Measures].[Ttl_RunTtl_Diff],
  [Measures].[NewAge],
  [Measures].[NewTotal]
  } 
 ON COLUMNS, 
  NON EMPTY 
    FILTER({[OrderedSet]} 
            , [Measures].[Running Total] > 15000 )
 ON ROWS FROM [Model]
```